# What is the JacksonDB equivalent of db.collection.find({},{"fieldName":1})?

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper

I am new to Jackson DB. Now I know that to get the entire document list of a collection using Jackson we need to do :

```
COllectionClass.coll.find().toArray();
```

which is Jackson DB equivalent to the mongodb command :

```
db.collection.find()
```

So What is the Jackson DB equivalent of say :

```
db.collection.find({},{"fieldName":1, "_id":0})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given [here](http://mongojack.org/queries.html), This might be helpful to you. **(not tested)**

```
coll.find(DBQuery.is(),//add your criteria for search here
    DBProjection.include("fieldName")).toArray();
```

Comment: Can you clarify, what does DBQuery.is("published", true) mean?

Comment: To know more about different mongo jackson annotations. [Check this](http://developer.vz.net/2011/12/01/jackson-annotations-with-mongodb/)